# How hide Android's default back navigation button React Native

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

[image]

[image]

Hello!

In my React Native app I have custom back button (as you can see on IOS screenshot).
But Android adds its own back button.
How I can hide it?

I know that I can hide my custom button on Android, but in some cases I have back button with custom text, so for me only one solution is to hide Android's default back button.

I am using https://reactnavigation.org v6

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with `headerBackVisible` prop in stack navigation setup

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#headerbackvisible

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the headerBackVisible option to the Stack navigator like this:

```js
 <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName="Dashboard"
      screenOptions={{ headerBackVisible: false }}>
      </Stack.Naavigator>
```